# postfix timeouts on every mail server

Tags: domain-name-system, postfix

I just ran into problem after not enough inodes on a server, which I fixed into this postfix problem. I use
dovecot+amavis+spamassasin+dovecot+postfix

I found this error

> postfix/smtpd[1775]: warning: hostname foo.domain.tld does not resolve to addres

Emails are now stuck in mailq and it looks like this:

> (delivery temporarily suspended: connect to alt2.gmail-smtp-in.l.google.com[142.250.4.26]:25: Connection timed out)
>                                                reciever@gmail.com

I already tried:

```
import_environment = MAIL_CONFIG MAIL_DEBUG MAIL_LOGTAG TZ XAUTHORITY DISPLAY LANG=C RESOLV_MULTI=on
```

and

```
smtp_host_lookup = native
```

Sadly, none of this worked.

Here is my

**/etc/hosts**

```
127.0.0.1 localhost
127.0.1.1 foo.domain.tld  foo

# The following lines are desirable for IPv6 capable hosts
::1     localhost ip6-localhost ip6-loopback
ff02::1 ip6-allnodes
ff02::2 ip6-allrouters
```

**/etc/postfix/main.conf**

```
 See /usr/share/postfix/main.cf.dist for a commented, more complete version


# Debian specific:  Specifying a file name will cause the first
# line of that file to be used as the name.  The Debian default
# is /etc/mailname.
#myorigin = /etc/mailname

smtpd_banner = $myhostname ESMTP $mail_name (Debian/GNU)
biff = no

# appending .domain is the MUA's job.
append_dot_mydomain = no

# Uncomment the next line to generate "delayed mail" warnings
#delay_warning_time = 4h

readme_directory = no

# See http://www.postfix.org/COMPATIBILITY_README.html -- default to 2 on
# fresh installs.
compatibility_level = 2



# TLS parameters
smtpd_tls_cert_file = /etc/ssl/ansible/cert.pem
smtpd_tls_key_file = /etc/ssl/ansible/key.pem
smtpd_use_tls = yes
smtpd_tls_session_cache_database = btree:${data_directory}/smtpd_scache
smtp_tls_session_cache_database = btree:${data_directory}/smtp_scache

# See /usr/share/doc/postfix/TLS_README.gz in the postfix-doc package for
# information on enabling SSL in the smtp client.

smtpd_relay_restrictions = permit_mynetworks permit_sasl_authenticated defer_unauth_destination
myhostname = foo.domain.tld
alias_maps = 

alias_database = hash:/etc/aliases, hash:/var/lib/mailman/data/aliases
myorigin = /etc/mailname
mydestination = foo.domain.tld
relayhost = 
mynetworks = 127.0.0.0/8 [::1]/128
mailbox_size_limit = 0
recipient_delimiter = +
inet_interfaces = all
inet_protocols = ipv4, ipv6
dovecot_destination_recipient_limit = 1
virtual_transport = dovecot
smtpd_sasl_type = dovecot
smtpd_sasl_path = private/auth
content_filter = amavis:[127.0.0.1]:10024
receive_override_options = no_address_mappings
virtual_alias_maps = proxy:mysql:/etc/postfix/mysql-virtual_forwardings.cf, proxy:mysql:/etc/postfix/mysql-virtual_email2email.cf
message_size_limit = 52428800
smtp_tls_exclude_ciphers = RC4, aNULL
smtpd_tls_exclude_ciphers = RC4, aNULL
smtpd_tls_mandatory_protocols = !SSLv2, !SSLv3
smtpd_tls_protocols = !SSLv2,!SSLv3
smtp_tls_protocols = !SSLv2,!SSLv3
smtp_tls_security_level = may
owner_request_special = no
body_checks = regexp:/etc/postfix/body_checks
nested_header_checks = regexp:/etc/postfix/nested_header_checks
mime_header_checks = regexp:/etc/postfix/mime_header_checks
header_checks = regexp:/etc/postfix/header_checks
maildrop_destination_recipient_limit = 1
maildrop_destination_concurrency_limit = 1
smtpd_client_message_rate_limit = 100
smtpd_client_restrictions = check_client_access mysql:/etc/postfix/mysql-virtual_client.cf
smtpd_sender_restrictions = check_sender_access regexp:/etc/postfix/tag_as_originating.re , permit_mynetworks, permit_sasl_authenticated, check_sender_access mysql:/etc/postfix/mysql-virtual_sender.cf, check_sender_access regexp:/etc/postfix/tag_as_foreign.re
smtpd_helo_restrictions = permit_sasl_authenticated, permit_mynetworks, check_helo_access regexp:/etc/postfix/helo_access, reject_invalid_hostname, reject_non_fqdn_hostname, reject_invalid_helo_hostname, reject_unknown_helo_hostname, check_helo_access regexp:/etc/postfix/blacklist_helo
smtpd_helo_required = yes
proxy_read_maps = $local_recipient_maps $mydestination $virtual_alias_maps $virtual_alias_domains $sender_bcc_maps $virtual_mailbox_maps $virtual_mailbox_domains $relay_recipient_maps $relay_domains $canonical_maps $sender_canonical_maps $recipient_canonical_maps $relocated_maps $transport_maps $mynetworks $smtpd_sender_login_maps
smtpd_sender_login_maps = proxy:mysql:/etc/postfix/mysql-virtual_sender_login_maps.cf
relay_recipient_maps = mysql:/etc/postfix/mysql-virtual_relayrecipientmaps.cf
relay_domains = mysql:/etc/postfix/mysql-virtual_relaydomains.cf
transport_maps = hash:/var/lib/mailman/data/transport-mailman, proxy:mysql:/etc/postfix/mysql-virtual_transports.cf
smtpd_tls_security_level = may
smtpd_recipient_restrictions = permit_mynetworks, permit_sasl_authenticated, reject_unauth_destination, reject_rbl_client zen.spamhaus.org, check_recipient_access mysql:/etc/postfix/mysql-virtual_recipient.cf, check_recipient_access mysql:/etc/postfix/mysql-virtual_policy_greylist.cf
greylisting = check_policy_service inet:127.0.0.1:10023
smtpd_restriction_classes = greylisting
smtpd_sasl_authenticated_header = yes
broken_sasl_auth_clients = no
smtpd_sasl_auth_enable = yes
sender_bcc_maps = proxy:mysql:/etc/postfix/mysql-virtual_outgoing_bcc.cf
virtual_gid_maps = mysql:/etc/postfix/mysql-virtual_gids.cf
virtual_uid_maps = mysql:/etc/postfix/mysql-virtual_uids.cf
virtual_mailbox_base = /var/vmail
virtual_mailbox_maps = proxy:mysql:/etc/postfix/mysql-virtual_mailboxes.cf
virtual_mailbox_domains = proxy:mysql:/etc/postfix/mysql-virtual_domains.cf
virtual_alias_domains = 
smtpd_tls_CAfile = /etc/ssl/ansible/ca.pem
```

Comment: Try uncommenting `#myorigin = /etc/mailname` and check that the host.domain.tld in that file matches what you list in your /etc/hosts for the mail host. myorigin can also be an apex domain. BTW You also do not have localhost as a final destination.. I don't think local-only mail will deliver.

Comment: Did not helped, and also no IP address can be resolved from the server ouside, but I can establish connection from other servers. Firewall is Opened on that ports..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was due to missconfiguration in NFT. I was droping connections.

Comment: Glad you fig'd it out.. You should post a full(er) brief answer, though, for others.

Comment: I had mistake in my NF Tables, I was blocking all output traffic.